# Porque Spring lanza estas excepciones al tratar de mandar un Formulario?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

soy nuevo en esta comunidad y estoy tratando de iniciar en el mundo mvc de Spring, me ha tocado realizar un metodo para cargar un formulario pero estoy teniendo inconveniente a la hora de tratar de probar que ocurre al tratar de mandar el formulario! tambien me ocurre con metodos anteriores para validar si esta vacio el campo!

**2022-01-12 19:46:20.139  WARN 14660 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'idAutor' for method parameter type String is not present]**

Aclaro que al crear otros metodos post de formularios he tenido el mismo error, espero su ayuda para este beginner dev! muchas gracias!

pd2: aclaro que tambien me ocurria al tratar de mandar cosas vacias en vez de largar la excepcion!

Y aqui los metodos get y post:

```
    @GetMapping("/registrarLibro")
    public String cargarLibro(ModelMap model){
        List<Autor> autores = autorRepositorio.findAll();
        List<Editorial> editoriales = editorialRepositorio.findAll();

        model.put("autores",autores);
        model.put("editoriales",editoriales);
        return "registrarLibro.html";
    }

    @PostMapping("/registrar")
    public String registrar(ModelMap modelo, @RequestParam String titulo, @RequestParam Long isbn, @RequestParam  Integer anio, @RequestParam Integer ejemplares,@RequestParam String idAutor,@RequestParam String idEditorial ){
        try {
            libroService.registrarLibro(isbn,titulo,anio,ejemplares,idAutor,idEditorial);

        } catch (ErrorService e) {
            List<Autor> autores = autorRepositorio.findAll();
            List<Editorial> editoriales = editorialRepositorio.findAll();

            modelo.put("autores",autores);
            modelo.put("editoriales",editoriales);
            modelo.put("error",e.getMessage());
            modelo.put("titulo",titulo);
            modelo.put("isbn",isbn);
            modelo.put("anio",anio);
            modelo.put("ejemplares",ejemplares);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "registrarLibro.html";
        }
        modelo.put("titulo","Enhorabuena!");
        modelo.put("descripcion","Tu libro fue guardado satisfactoriamente!");
        return "exito.html";
    }
```

```
Aqui les dejo el formulario!!
```

```
    <h2>Ingresa sus datos</h2>

<form th:action="@{/registrar}" method="post">

  <p th:if="${error != null}" th:text="${error}" style="color: red; "></p>


  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="titulo" class="form-label">Titulo del libro</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo" name="titulo" autocomplete="off" th:value="${titulo}" >
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="isbn" class="form-label"  >ISBN </label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="isbn" name="isbn" required th:value="${isbn}">
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="autor" class="form-label">Ingresa el año</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="autor" name="anio"  th:value="${anio}">
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <label  class="form-label">Autor</label><br>
    <select name="autor" >
      <option th:each="autor : ${autores}" th:value="${autor.id}" th:text="${autor.nombre}" ></option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <label  class="form-label">Editorial</label><br>
    <select name="autor" >
      <option th:each="editorial : ${editoriales}" th:value="${editorial.id}" th:text="${editorial.nombre}" ></option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="ejemplares" class="form-label">cantidad de ejemplares</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="ejemplares" name="ejemplares" required th:value="${ejemplares}">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar Libro</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx. Haría falta ver qué formulario estás enviando. Por favor, ve a [edit] tu pregunta y añádelo...

Comment: Hola! gracias! 
Ahi he añadido la parte del cuerpo del formulario, es un error que me esta llevando tiempo solucionar!

Comment: Fui a mirar tu edición y sólo aparecía el cambio en el título. :/  Por favor, ponlo como texto y guíate por como está marcado el bloque de código existente en tu pregunta

Comment: Si cargas el formulario sin colocar el parametro, es necesario que coloques esto: RequestParam(required=false).